# I can get RSTP to stream to AWS IVS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ffmpeg, rtsp, nvidia-jetson

I'm using ffmpeg running on jetson nano but I can't it to stream to aws IVS. I get a bunch of errors

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc -rtsp_transport udp -i "rtsp://192.168.1.193:8554/" -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*2)" -vf scale=640:480 -reorder_queue_size 4000 -max_delay 10000000 -vcodec libx264 -b:v 500k -pix_fmt yuv420p -f flv rtmps://<IVS-ingest-server>/app/<IVS-stream-key>
```

How do I resolve this problem on jetson nano